# Adding a Total Column to a Matrix-Visual that only sums spcific columns

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that has (simplified) the columns CustID, Action, Date

I then have a matrix visual that has Action as Columns, CustID AS Rows and Count(Action) as Values.

Now I need an extra column that sums only some of the Columns, not all like the Total. In Excel this is =SUMME(B11:K11), where K12 and K13 are the columns not to be summed.

Is this possible in PBI Matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was, that I had a table column in the column section of the matrx visual. than, when I add a measure it is only available in drill, not as extra column. I solved it with pivoting that column and use the new columns in data section. than I can add measures to the data section and they get also new columns.
would be nice, if I could use the column section and add measures

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a measure.

```
    (new_measure_name) = 'table'[field to add] + 'table'[field to add]
```

After you create the measure you can add it to the matrix and double check you math that it adds up like you want.

Good luck!

Comment: See my answer. It works for me, but should be simpler to do. Maybe you know a way to put a measure to a matrix that has a table column in the column section?